# iOS UI Automation: check if tested application is active

Tags: javascript, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I need a way to check whether the tested application is active (running) or not. All that I have is a custom javascript which activated via Instruments Automation tool and I can't use objective-c for that purpose. So I need a solution based on UIAxxx objects or something else. Any help will be appreciated.